# UIDocumentInteractionController on iphoneX with iOS 11.1.2

Tags: ios

When I use UIDocumentInteractionController on iphoneX with iOS 11.1.2, it doesn't show, and log on the console as:

```
[ShareSheet] ERROR: <_UIDICActivityViewController: 0x107075c00> timed out waiting to establish a connection to the ShareUI view service extension.
```

but the same code runs ok on other device with iOS 11.1.2, only the iphoneX cannot preview the documentInteraction menu. Is there some thing wrong with my code? Please tell me if you find the solution.

My code:

```
    var doc: UIDocumentInteractionController?

fileprivate func openWithOtherApp(with url: URL) -> Void {
    let doc = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url)
    self.doc = doc
    doc.delegate = self
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        guard let weakSelf = self else {
            return
        }
        if weakSelf.doc?.presentOpenInMenu(from: weakSelf.view.bounds, in: weakSelf.view, animated: true) != true {
            Toast(message: "No app on you iPhone can open this file.")
        }
    }
}
```

delegate:

```
  extension UniversalPreviewController: UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

        func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
            return self
        }

        func documentInteractionControllerRectForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> CGRect {
            return self.view.bounds
        }

        func documentInteractionControllerViewForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIView? {
            return self.view
        }

        func documentInteractionControllerWillBeginPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) {
            NSLog("documentInteractionControllerWillBeginPreview")
        }

        func documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) {
            self.doc = nil
        }
    }
```

My Latest Test:

When i use permanent file url(drag the file into the project filelist), It works.

```
  let permanentUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "INBOX24-2.2-resolv", withExtension: "conf")
  self.doc = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: permanentUrl!)
  //permanentUrl:file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/40F14112-208E-4A97-8214-D55CC8E597C4/xxx.app/INBOX24-2.2-resolv.conf
```

But when i change to the real code that files storage on the apps documents directory it doesn't work,code like this:

```
let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: storedPath
self.doc = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: url)
//url:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9624FFB3-8CB0-437C-A67B-C71AAB314370/Documents/INBOX24-2.2-resolv.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue in my iPhone, I just restarted my iPhone and it was resolved.